# Android to server 500 error

Tags: android

I am trying to send user informations to server via open connection and it returns user id in JSON. Everything is OK but when i am trying to read user id with getInputStream i can't read it (i take 500 server error). When i try it with getErrorStream and log the result the JSON is come here. Why ? How can i overcome it ?

```
public String bilgiyigonder() {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        try{
            Log.i("tago" ,"Veri Tabani bilgiyi gonder" + is.trim());
            Log.i("tago" , "Veri Tabani bilgiyi gonder" + urrl);
            Log.i("tago" , "VeriTabani bilgiyi gonder" + longi);
            Log.i("tago" ,"VeriTabani bilgiyi gonder" + lat);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://185.22.184.103/project/connection.php?name="+URLEncoder.encode("Faarık Fazıl", "ISO-8859-9")+"&url="+urrl+"&long="+longi+"&lat="+lat).openConnection();
            Log.i("tago" ,"VeriTabani bagı kurdum");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 ( compatible ) ");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + charset);

        try(OutputStream output = connection.getOutputStream()){
            output.write(query.getBytes(charset));
            //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            //while((inputline=in.readLine()) != null){
             //   Log.i("tago" , inputline);
            //}in.close();
            //InputStream response = connection.getInputStream();
            Log.i("tago", "VeriTabani yazdım");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("tago" , "VeriTabani yazamadım");
        }
        try {
            int status = connection.getResponseCode();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()));
            String inputline;
            while((inputline=in.readLine()) != null){
                Log.i("tago" , inputline);
                JsondanCevir(inputline);
            }in.close();
            Log.i("tago" , "VeriTabani status= " +status);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "alabama";
    }
```

Comment: a 500 means the server you are using is the one thats crashing no the android app

Comment: according to my researches mostly it is Tomer , but my friend, who work for server, insisted about problem is related with android side.

Comment: your *friend* is not your *friend*. Tomer is right. You may have constructed an unexpected request though... but without more details on the requirements, Tomer is right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the answer, try using this code and share the result, the code is not tested but if the server response is correct this could be works, else, verify your server.

PD: In test use this plain code, any additional property or doInput/output is not required

```
package com.test.test;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

class receiveResponse {
    String Response(String name, String urrl, String longi, String lat)
            throws IOException {
                String url = "http://185.22.184.103/project/connection.php?name="+URLEncoder.encode(name, "ISO-8859-9")+"&url="+urrl+"&long="+longi+"&lat="+lat;
        URL link = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) link.openConnection();
        conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);

        BufferedInputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());

        int ch;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((ch = is.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) ch);
        }
        is.close();
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```